# How to order by different meta keys in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a rental custom post type. The rentals have prices, the price is stored in the rental table. The rentals also have a meta key "featured". It has a value of "on" or "off".

What I need to do is, list the rentals so that the featured comes first, the featured are ordered by date, and then list the other rentals, and the other rentals that are not featured should be ordered by price.

This is my actual  query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*, 
   FROM wp_posts 
   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
   INNER JOIN wp_st_rental as tb ON wp_posts.ID = tb.post_id 
   WHERE 1=1 AND 
   ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships 
   WHERE      term_taxonomy_id IN (253) ) ) AND 
   ( wp_postmeta.meta_key =    'is_featured' ) AND 
   wp_posts.post_type = 'st_rental' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
   AND wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_st_location_relationships
   WHERE 1=1  AND post_type IN ('st_rental')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
   ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC, CAST(st_rental_price as DECIMAL) ASC 
   LIMIT 0, 350
```

In this actual query I could manage to get the featured rentals first, and then the others, but all of them are ordered by price.
This should be changed, so that the featured are ordered by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try ordering with the following `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'is_featured' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'is_featured'
              THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column)            -- integer number of seconds
              ELSE CAST(st_rental_price AS UNSIGNED) END  -- integer rental price
```

The second `CASE` expression in the above `ORDER BY` assumes that the date column is called `date_column`, because I did not actually see anything in your original query which seemed to fit this.

The logic behind the second `CASE` expression is that for featured items it will order by the integer number of seconds in the date column since the epoch, otherwise it will order by the price, treated as an unsigned integer.

Comment: This was my final solution:
  CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'on' THEN wp_posts.post_date  END DESC,
            CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'off' THEN CAST(act.price as DECIMAL)  END ASC";

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IF` to conditionally select the second sort field:

```
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC,
         IF(wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'on', the_date, CAST(st_rental_price as DECIMAL)) ASC
```

Comment: _All_ outputs from a given `CASE` expression should ideally be the same type.  This might run in MySQL, but would probably fail for any other RDBMS.